# How to listen to changes if you are using dart only package(riverpod) or how to use Provider where there is no context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I am learning flutter and it would be easy to understand if i get an example of listening to changes in dart only package aka riverpod.
I was using Provider in class where there is no stateless or stateful widget(basically no Buildcontext).

So i was passing context from other class to this class like this although it works but i feel its not right way.

```
class SaveToLocal {
  final BuildContext context;
  SaveToLocal(this.context);

 foo(){
  //used context here
  var model = Provider.of<MyList>(context, listen: false);
  }
}
```

then i came across riverpod where dart only package doesn't require context but i was confused as i was not able to find things like ProviderScope.I searched also examples but most of them are on flutter_riverpod not on riverpod.
[This example on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod/example) is using FutureProvider what if i wanna just fetch from model

By model i mean

```
class MyList extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<String> _myList = [];
  List<String> get myList => _myList;
  
  foo(){
    //some task here
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

So here are questions
1.Is this appropriate way of using context
2.Is there any other way that i can achieve this
3.Can i get a simple example like CounterApp where read and watch is shown?

Comment: flutter_riverpod also doesn't require context

Comment: @MrRandom yeah it worked fine i just got little confused,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i got confused i thought riverpod is only for dart only classes but it was for non-flutter apps(saying after reading [reso coder's article](https://resocoder.com/2020/11/27/flutter-riverpod-tutorial-the-better-provider/)), as i tried further with flutter_riverpod and used without context (as said by Mr Random)and worked fine.

```
class SaveToLocal {
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  foo(){
    var model = container.read(listProvider);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question the answer is no: context shouldn't be saved in some external class since it might lead to issues.

I link you these example of how to manage state properly across the application:

- https://medium.com/codechai/provider-state-management-in-flutter-d453e73537c5